# how to display avatar in forum-list (advanced-forum)

Tags: views

Any suggestions? I'm interested in how to display the avatar last post in forum list. I tried to display the avatar as $picture but is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You may include the picture of the author of the forum topic by configuring the corresponding view:

admin/build/views/edit/advanced_forum_topic_list

HTH